# What's the probability of winning this chance based prize?

Tags: probability

Imagine a contest in which you need to collect 16 unique tokens.  Let's letter the tokens A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M,N,O,P.  In order to win the prize, I must turn in a collection that contains all 16 of these unique tokens.  I get these tokens by opening a box.  The box will have a random token inside of it.  I will be able to collect 38 of these boxes.  Furthermore, I may trade in five tokens to receive any token I don't already have.

With those rules, I know that if I collect a total of 38 tokens, as long as I naturally get 11 unique tokens I can take 25 of my other 27 duplicate tokens to trade them in for the 5 unique tokens I didn't get.

So effectively, the simplest form of this problem is... given 38 random rolls on a 16-sided dice, what are the odds that I will get 11 or more different results?

I am interested both in the actual answer and the logic and process behind the math to get the answer.

Comment: You have a 12-state Markov chain with states $11, 10, 9, …, 0$ being the remaining number of new tokens you need. The transition probability is $P=(P_{ij})$, a $12 \times 12$ matrix. You want $P^{38}$.

Answer (score 1):

This is equivalent to : $N=38$ balls are thrown into $M=16$ urns. What is the probability that at least $P=11$ urns are non-empty?

The probability that exactly $p$ urns are not empty is

$$ \frac{\binom{M}{p} p! \left\{ {N \atop p} \right\}}{M^N} $$
where $ \left\{ {N \atop p} \right\}$ is the Stirling number of the second kind. Hence the answer is

$$ \frac{1}{M^N} \sum_{p=P}^M \binom{M}{p} p! \left\{ {N \atop p} \right\} = 0.9998807$$